# CLLocationManager didChangeAuthorization is running in a loop if I use it to initialize my locationmanager

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I am wanting to start updating locations as soon as a user gives the app permission. I set up this code

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:    (CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
NSLog(@"the status changed!!!");
if (status==kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized){

    NSLog(@"we are live");
    _mainlocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _mainlocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    _mainlocationManager.distanceFilter=100;  //look for changes >100m while app is open
    _mainlocationManager.delegate = self;
    [_mainlocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
}
```

and what I get is when the user grants the app permission, it just repeats the two nslog statuses endlessly. I was assuming it would only be called once when the user changed the status. Additionally, it will do this when I reopen the app (after permission was already granted the previous time it was opened).

```
2014-02-07 07:54:58.457 G[5558:70b] the status changed!!!
2014-02-07 07:54:58.457 G[5558:70b] we are live
2014-02-07 07:54:58.463 G[5558:70b] the status changed!!!
2014-02-07 07:54:58.463 G[5558:70b] we are live
2014-02-07 07:54:58.468 G[5558:70b] the status changed!!!
2014-02-07 07:54:58.468 G[5558:70b] we are live
2014-02-07 07:54:58.473 G[5558:70b] the status changed!!!
2014-02-07 07:54:58.473 G[5558:70b] we are live
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of CCLocationManager? In order to receive the delegate message locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus: you must already have created an instance of it.

Comment: You are exactly right, that was the issue. I had thought I had to re-initialize it. Thanks!  I just removed everything except [_mainlocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

I guess I was creating an infinite number of mainlocationmanagers that needed the message.